# passing array to f.select ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my rails application in the views/cards/_form i have the code for a f.select field:

```
<%= f.select :tag_speciality, options_for_select(@subdomain.tag_speciality), {}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
```

That give me the output:

```
<select class="form-control" name="card[tag_speciality]" id="card_tag_speciality">
  <option value="Professor de Yoga">Professor de Yoga</option>
  <option value="Professora de Yoga">Professora de Yoga</option>
  <option value="Estúdio de Yoga">Estúdio de Yoga</option>
</select>
```

In my migration file i have:

```
add_column :cards, :tag_speciality, :string, array: true
```

When i go to the form and select any option, for example, "Professor de Yoga", and save, i get the result:

```
[]
```

instead of:

`["Professor de Yoga"]`

This is my controller:

```html
  def index
    @cards = Card.all
  end

  def create
    @card = @user.cards.new card_params

    respond_to do |format|
      if @card.save
        format.html { redirect_to cards_from_subdomain_path(@subdomain.id), notice: 'Card was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @card }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @card.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @card.update(card_params)
        format.html { redirect_to cards_from_subdomain_path(@subdomain.id), notice: 'Card was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @card }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @card.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
 
  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def card_params
    params.require(:card).permit(
      :name,
      :phone,
      :email,
      :cover,
      :is_published,
      :subdomain_id,
      :domain_id,
      :profile_id,
      :is_solidarity,
      :tag_speciality,
      :tag_location,
      user_id: []
    )
  end
end
```

Is there anything that am i missing?
Thanks

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: Did you put :tag_location in permitted params in your controller?

Comment: yes, just added the controller, the tag_location is already in the permitted params in my controller, look like that the issue is something about it be an array:true field, if it was a simple string field, it would be saving normaly...

Comment: Did you mean to show us the tag_speciality column in your migration file? Only that you showed us tag_location instead.

Comment: Yes, sorry, just corrected, the migration file for tag_speciality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditto @EJ2015.

Just add

```
@card.tag_speciality.push(card_params[:tag_speciality])
@card.save
```

to your `create`.

```
respond_to do |format|
      if @card.tag_speciality.push(card_params[:tag_speciality]) && @card.save
        format.html { redirect_to cards_from_subdomain_path(@subdomain.id), notice: 'Card was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @card }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @card.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

Comment: Great, on create it worked :) , but how could i do on update? I tried: 'if @card.tag_speciality.push(card_params[:tag_speciality]) && @card.update(params)' but didn't work!!

Comment: The problem is that when you do @card.update(params) you are assigning the string value from the params directly to the array column again. You can do it the same way as the create method, assigning the values to attributes first and then save the object.

Comment: One more question, what if i have more fields that are array? how can i set them in controller, should i open another question for that?

Answer (score 1):

Since your tag_speciality is an array column, you need to assign the data using array method in your controller.

```
@card.tag_speciality.push(card_params[:tag_speciality])
@card.save
```

Of course you need to modify the assignment of other attributes too. By the way, you can see what went wrong in your server log. In this case you should see that the database rejected commits.

Comment: thanks for answer, where in the controller i could use the code that you sugested? Would be in the "def card_params"?

Comment: It'll be in your create and update actions. You can do it as @ravi suggested.